# ADT 20's AVD create dialog doesnt have the Device Selection drop down?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt, android-2.2-froyo, android-virtual-device

It was posted on the android developer site that the new ADT 20 will have the feature to create AVD for actually devices available in the market like Asus Nexus 7, Motorola XOOM, etc....

But after upgrading to ADT I still see the old AVD create dialog and no Devices drop down. Was it released it ADT 20 or it is something they are still working on?

Thanks
Akh

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erd2k6EKxCQ   Watch min 5:00 to 7:00.

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the release notes I do not see any indication that they added support for the specific platforms mentioned.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html#notes

So I would guess that it was not included.